# Indexed addition without IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java

I have `n` objects each of them with an identifying number. I get them unsorted but the range of indexes `(0, n-1)` is used to identify them. I want to access them as fastest as possible. I suppose that an ArrayList would be the best option, I'd add the object with identifier `n` at the position of the ArrayList with index `n` by:

```
list.add(identifier, object);
```

The problem is that when I am adding the objects I get an `IndexOutOfBounds Exception` because I'm adding them unsorted and the `size()` is smaller although I know that previous positions will also be filled.

Another option is to use a HashMap but I suppose that  this will decrease performance.

Do you know a collection that has the behavior described above?

Comment: Why do you think that accessing values in HashMap will decrease performance, specially when what you are describing is an ideal condition for HashMap to be used. A `Map` provides fastest access when you have data in the form of `Key-Value` pair.

Comment: I know, but HashMap doesn't require integer keys to be in a range like I have. I suppose it because, with these conditions (there is a bijective map between the range (1,n) and the objects), data can be stored sequentially (Array) and access may be faster (?)

Comment: Well, as far as `accessing` value is concerned, ArrayList or Array can not beat `Map`. And if you want your keys to be in specific range, then you can handle it manually, using `if-else`. It would be on-time problem, but later on, will help you to access values.

Comment: Oh, cool, I didn't know that `Map` was faster in these cases. Thank you all.

Comment: Nonsense! Both Array and ArrayList offer constant-time access, and don't need to calculate the hashcode or traverse buckets (in case of collision). Linked lists require sequential access, and they'd be slower.

Comment: @RohitJain You can't say that a map is faster than an array to access items.

Comment: Both arrays and `ArrayList` provide random access in constant time, as Tom mentions. `HashMaps` basically store the data in an array, where indices are `hashCode mod array_length` (simplified). Therefore the underlying storage is not that much different (leaving out collisions for now).

Comment: @assylias I am only saying that in case OP has something in the form of `key-value`. Since he's accessing values based on some property, may be some numbers, `Map` is what he wants.

Comment: @RohitJain You said *"In Arrays or ArrayList, data are stored sequentially, that is why accessing is slower. Whereas, in Map it is in the form of mapping. You give the key, you get the corresponding value, directly."* => That is factually incorrect. You seem to imply that to get the n-th item of an array, all the items from 0 to n need to be read.

Comment: @assylias Aw! Did I? Really I didn't mean it that way. I was just refering `Map` for the case of `key-value` access. And I think I got it the wrong way :(

Comment: @Mudu aren't the underlying arrays in hashmaps normally larger than the expected number of items, though? To avoid collisions?

Comment: @chm052 I think so, and the array is re-created larger as the number of items grows. I don't know the Java implementation though, this is only what I know about data structures in general.

Comment: @chm052 The documentation on `HashMap` is quite interesting and states quite a lot on this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: "indexes from 0 to `n-1` (not sparse)" sounds like *the* usecase for a plain old array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know a collection that has the behavior described above?

It sounds like you need a plain old Java array.  And if you need it as a collection, then use "Arrays.asList(...)" to create a `List` wrapper for it.

Now this won't work if you needed to add or remove elements from the array / collection, but it sounds like you don't need to from your problem description.

If you *do* need to add / remove elements (as distinct from using `set` to update the element at a given position, then Peter Lawrey's approach is best.

---

By contrast, a `HashMap<Integer, Object>` would be an expensive alternative.  At a rough estimate, I'd say it that "indexing" operations would be at least 10 times slower, and the data structure would take 10 times the space compared to an equivalent array or `ArrayList` type.  A hash table based solution is only really a viable alternative (from a performance perspective) if the array is large and sparse.

Comment: I'm extending Arraylist with my class, that's why I was using collections. But I always can put is as a field. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you get the indexes out of order.  This requires you to add dummy entries which may be filled later.

```
int indexToAdd = ...
E elementToAdd = ...

while(list.size() <= indexToAdd) list.add(null);
list.set(indexToAdd, elementToAdd);
```

This will allow you to add entries beyond the current end of the list.

---

The Javadoc for [List.add(int, E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) and [List.set(int, E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) both state

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

If you attempt to add entries beyond the end

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(1, 1);
```

you get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:612)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:426)
    at Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

Comment: Assuming we're talking about an ArrayList, there's no need to do anything of the sort (adding dummy entries). Either set(int, E) or add(int, E) will allow arbitrary indices in range to be set, and ensureCapacity() can be used to grow the list if necessary (for the case where n is unknown at the start).

Comment: @TomJohnson Can you provide an example of this because that not how I read the Javadoc?

Comment: They will allow arbitrary indices *in range* to be set. Here you're trying to add outside the current range, so you need to extend the range first - call ensureCapacity(1) and you can add. Any unset values will be initialized to null. Of course, if you know the maximum n at the start it's better to initialise your ArrayList to the required size.

Comment: The `ensureCapacity(int)` doesn't change the size so while it might be more efficient to call this first you still need to add the "empty" values to increase the size.

Comment: You're quite right! My apologies :) I don't know why I was so sure you could insert randomly in the ArrayList as if it were an Array (as long as it was suitably sized). So sure I didn't need to actually *test* it.

Comment: I was thinking of a Vector: that *does* allow the behaviour I was referring to (if you use set(), and using setSize() to grow), and arguably is the best fit of the Collections classes for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much more expensive a `HashMap<Integer, T>` would be. [`Integer.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode%28%29) is quite efficient, though the only really expensive operation might be copying the data into a new larger array as the number of items increases. However, if you know your `n`, you could use a **normal array**.

As an alternative, you could implement your own [`Map<Integer, T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that does not use the hash code but the `Integer` itself. Before you do this, make sure that neither an array is sufficient nor `HashMap` is efficient enough!

Comment: The hashcode of integer simply returns the underlying int. Can't be faster than that.

Comment: HashMap would be a lot more expensive, and use a lot more memory.  (Probably ~10 times as much memory ...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have at least two good options.

The first is to use a straight Java array initialized to the appropriate length, then add objects with the syntax:

```
    theArray[i] = object;
```

The second would be to use a HashMap, and add objects with the syntax:

```
    theMap.put(i, object);
```

I'm not sure what performance issues you're worried about, but adding elements within the range, clearing (out of an array) or removing (out of a HashMap), and finding elements from a given index (or key, for a HashMap) are all O(1) for both structures. I would also suggest taking a look at [Wikipedia's list of data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures) if neither of these seem good.